# Liferay and sharepoint integration

Tags: sharepoint, liferay

I am looking for some resources or guideline for integration of liferay with sharepoint. I want to pull data from liferay and show it on sharepoint. Any CRM component available for this? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to check sharepoint.stackexchange.com - Stackoverflow is for programming related questions. About Liferay & SharePoint: Look into the Business Data Connectivity Services.

Comment: @moontear - Thanks for sending me to the right direction.